# Removing specific element from xml using sax with xerces library in c++

Tags: c++, xml, sax, xerces

My problem is that I want to remove lastfiles and all it's child element using sax with the API of Xerces in c++ language??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE config>
<config datecreated="20011210">
  <user>
    John Smith
  </user>
  <login>jsmith</login>
  <password>topsecret</password>
  <lastfiles>
    <lastfile timestamp="20011210T1002">accounts.txt</lastfile>
    <lastfile timestamp="20011190T1132">/home/jsmith/docs/letter.doc</lastfile>
  </lastfiles>
</config>
```

Comment: What was the last solution that you have attempted?

Comment: i hav tried to parse file from start to end element and skipping only the specific tag but it's not memory efficient ,is there anything which can directly remove the element and can store modified file in a other file ,any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Instead of parsing everything at once and then writing everything at once, try re-writing as you read. You'd need to use SAX2 parser instead of DOM parser for that. Make a flag `copyToOutput=true`, set it to `false` when you see start of `lastfiles`, and back to `true` when you see the closing tag. When you see anything else, check the flag, and either write data to the output, or skip it based on the value of the flag.

Comment: Why does memory efficiency matter here? this is a tiny data set - is this a toy example to represent a much bigger XML that you actually work with?  Unless you really need max efficiency, DOM is going to be easier than SAX to work with.